# Material autocomplete with filter does not work with async data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have prepared this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rppvg8?file=app%2Fasync-complete%2Fasync-complete.component.ts) the situation in my real app is very similar.

The data arrives later than the `<app-async-complete>` is rendered/ instatiated.

I already tried to trigger changeDetection manually but this also did not solve the issue.

Any quick tips?

## What is important

When I click on the working "example" and on the "sync case" I get the suggestions already on the initial focus. However this is not the case for the "async case". I want the same behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace your code like below-

```
 options: string[] = [];
 @Input('options') set onOptions(options: string[]){
    this.options = options;
    this.initAutoComplete()
  }
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initAutoComplete();
  }

  initAutoComplete(){
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. This actually works, However I get a tslint error `Property 'options' does not exist on type 'AsyncCompleteComponent'. Did you mean 'onOptions'?` Why is the setter called onOptions.

Comment: whoever downvoted this. Please remove the downvote. This solves the issue.

Comment: I forgot to add property `options: string[] = []`, and now it was in answered code. it will removed the tslint error.

Comment: hey, could you have a look at this follow-up [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56057683/how-to-fully-reset-mat-input-with-mat-autocomplete)?

Comment: Do you actually need to run your init script in the OnInit hook? I'm getting my source data via an @Input which fires before onInit anyway

Answer (score 1):

It's working, but it crashed because of the error you're getting.

You will just have to guard for null:

```
private _filter(value: string): string[] {
  const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

  // Here this.options can be null, so you get error when you .filter on null
  return this.options ? this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)) : this.options;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you I will edit my question. I forgot to describe an important piece.

Comment: Your solution helps but I do have to start typing into the field to get the "autocomplete panel".