# How to fully reset mat-input with mat-autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rppvg8-jsvfqa?file=app%2Fasync-complete%2Fasync-complete.component.html) I have a mat-autocomplete with async data.

When `(optionSelected)` fires (when I click on an option) I want the field to be fully resetted like its freshly rendered/ initialised.

Currently this solution has **two problems**!

1. after clearance I dont get any autosuggestions. I want to have the full autosuggestions back again.

==> I do have to blur and focus again or start typing.

2. when I **DON'T** type and just **blur** and **refocus** I still have the `mat-option.mat-selected` class attached to the panel since the reset did only affect the input value. I highlighted this with `background-color: red;`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make your reset function something like below

```
resetAutoInput(optVal, trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger, auto: MatAutoComplete) {
    setTimeout(_ => {
      auto.options.forEach((item) => {
        item.deselect()
      });
      this.myControl.reset('');
      trigger.openPanel();
      }, 100);
  }
```

and in your HTML code will be

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" #trigger="matAutocompleteTrigger" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="resetAutoInput($event.option.value, trigger, auto);">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: wow this works. I will mark this as answer soon! Thank you Sir.

Comment: I think resetting the formControl value to '' should do the trick

Comment: What about clearing input if there is not selected value? In this case I try to use input's `blur()` event, but in that case I cannot access the autocomplete value (if selected or not). Any idea?